# SQL Query for dropdown

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am trying to write dependent drop down query in asp.net.but it is not working please help me

How to write dependent dropdown SQL query in asp.net?

```
select * 
from Taluk 
where Districtid = 'Districtid'
```

Comment: check for parameterized queries

Comment: Can you elaborate it more or can you provide your code how you are trying to do it?

Comment: SELECT * FROM Taluk WHERE DistrictId = @DropdownValue

Comment: public DataTable getDistrictdetails()
        {
            return sqlhelperone.ExecuteSelectCommand("select * from District;", CommandType.Text);
        }
        public DataTable getTalukdetailsbydistrict(String District)
        {
            return sqlhelperone.ExecuteSelectCommand("select * from Taluk;", CommandType.Text);
        }

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by changing your query to

`select * from Taluk where Districtid=@Idof dropdown`

Or you can refer to this link for more information

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Creating-Cascading-DropDownLists-in-ASP.Net.aspx